# Wicket Test Error: component 'BookmarkablePageLink' is not type

Tags: wicket

I have created a linkpage FooPage, sothat when somebody clicks on this link, some text `"test test"` is desplayed to the user, so far good.

I have created the folloing basic page:

FooPage.java

```
public class FooPage extends WebPage {
public FooPage() {
    add(new Label("label", "test test"));
        }   }
```

FooPage.html

```
<div wicket:id="label"></div>
```

In MyPnel.java I add the created page as follow:

MyPanel.java

```
   public class MyPanel extends Panel{
add(new  BookmarkablePageLink<Void>("foobar", FooPage.class));
}
```

MyPanel.html:

```
<a wicket:id="foobar" href="FooPage"></a>
```

Now when I test the created component with junit as follows:

```
 @Test
 public void startPage() {
  wicketTester.assertComponent("foobar", FooPage.class);
}
```

I get the following error:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: component 'BookmarkablePageLink'
>   is not type:FooPage

Any idea what is the problem or hot to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ian already said, `assertComponent` checks that the type of the component is a subtype of a class. For your usecase you should use

```
wicketTester.assertBookmarkablePageLink("foobar", FooPage.class, new PageParameters());
```

Answer (score 2):

Should you not try

```
wicketTester.assertComponent("foobar", BookmarkablePageLink.class);
```

instead (since the component of ID "foobar" is of type `BookmarkablePageLink`)?

Comment: @lan Mashall: No it is FooPage Extends Webpage :(. Your solution did not help

Comment: @AhmedSalah, no, Ian is right, assertComponent tests the class of a component. And the class of "foobar" is BookmarkablePageLink. What you can do is let the wicketTester click on the link and than check that you are on your FooPage